# Finding highest value in field where first 2 numbers match

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

In Access 2016 VBA, I have a field that holds 8 digit numbers.

I need to find the highest numbers where the first 2 digits match. Some sample data :-

```
Dim tempsalesref As Double

tempsalesref = 34

34000001
34000002
34000003
```

So in this case my query would be based on 34, and the value to be returned, as it's the highest, would be 34000003.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why not implement it through the sql query? Max() over your column where column >= xy000000 and column <= xy999999.

Comment: @MikeMakarov Yes, this works. If you put as answer, I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the approach may be changed to simplify the task. Just use the sql query, a prototype with `x` and `y` being the key numbers:
`select Max(your_column ) from your_table where your_column >= xy000000 and your_column <= xy999999`